# Android App compat v7 resource error

Tags: android, eclipse

I am having jdk 6, eclipse luna, android sdk 4.4.2 (19), android sdk tools 23.0.5, android platform tools 21 and android sdk build tools 20. The appcompat v7 created by eclipse contains `android:widget.material.x.x` controls as a parent in `styles_base.xml`, which gives error of "resource not found". Its build target is android-19. However upgrading the sdk to android 5 should probably resolve the problem but I want to run it without upgrading to android sdk 5 version. I don't understand why does eclipse include material design in api level 19. Can anyone please point to the problem.

Comment: May be it's because your support Lib is updated and containing values-21 folder with material design.
and what is the problem in upgrading your sdk ?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project->android tools-> add support library(do this for your current project and app compat v7 folder)